# Harmon.ie splash screen keeps on Loading harmon.ie

Tags: outlook, splash-screen

When starting up outlook 2013, the harmon.ie plug in stays on the splash screen with Loading harmon.ie.
As a result the outlook.exe cpu raises but nothing happens.

Running outlook 2013 16-bit on a Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit version.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Harmon.ie developers instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing a .net issue. Would you please register the following registry key which instructs harmon.ie to use .net 4.x.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\PreferredCLRVersion]

@="v4.0"

---- Jean